# Synchronous generator to improve the power factor

Tags: synchronous

I read that a synchronous generator can be used to improve the power factor by operating it in an underexcited condition.

If not enough excitation is used, the generator will actually draw reactive power from the grid while it continues to deliver active power to it. The generator here is known as leading generator.

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is essentially accurate.

It might be preferable to refer to reactive power as reactive volt-amperes since it is actually a half-cycle to half cycle back and forth transfer of energy rather than a single-direction transfer of energy. The generator serves as a capacitor that complements an inductive load.

The term "leading generator" does not seem to be commonly used.